# Генерация нескольких случайных цифр python

Tags: python, python-3.x, случайные-числа

Есть функция random.randint(), которая генерирует 1 случайное число, но мне нужно сгенерировать таких чисел 6. Как это можно реализовать? У меня есть 1 вариант, по типу:

```
list = []
for i in range(1, 7)
    list += random.randint(0, 9)
```

Но мне кажется данный код выглядит не очень и его можно улучшить.

Comment: `[ random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(10)]`

Comment: `numpy.random.randint(0, 9, 10)`

Answer (score 4):

С использованием генератора списков

```
lst = [random.randint(0, 9) for _ in range(6)]
```

Comment: @ZeN Ответ непонятен?